# Creating a list of ints from a txt file

Tags: scala

I have an external list in a txt file, I need to grab the first string and use it as a key, thats fine it works, and then I need a list of the numbers afterwards. However I only get the first, what have I done wrong?
So current output would be SK1, 9 - SK2, 0 etc when I need this to be the full list not just the first number.
I am using Scala on Intelije

```
/**
  * Created by Andre on 10/11/2016.
  */
import scala.io.Source
import scala.io.StdIn.readInt
import scala.io.StdIn.readLine
import scala.collection.immutable.ListMap




object StockMarket extends App{

  // APPLICATION LOGIC
  // reads the data from text file
  val mapdata = readFile("data.txt")
  // print data to check it's been read in correctly
  println(mapdata)


  // *******************************************************************************************************************
  // UTILITY FUNCTIONS

  // reads data file - comma separated file
  def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, Int] = {
    // create buffer to build up map as we read each line
    var mapBuffer: Map[String, Int] = Map()
    try {
      for (line <- Source.fromFile(filename).getLines()) {     // for each line
      val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList     // split line at , and convert to List

        // add element to map buffer
        // splitline is line from file as List, e.g. List(Bayern Munich, 24)
        // use head as key
        // tail is a list, but need just the first (only in this case) element, so use head of tail and convert to int
        mapBuffer = mapBuffer ++ Map(splitline.head -> splitline.tail.head.toInt)

      }
    } catch {
      case ex: Exception => println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
    }
    mapBuffer
  }
}
```

My external List

```
SK1, 9, 7, 2, 0, 7, 3, 7, 9, 1, 2, 8, 1, 9, 6, 5, 3, 2, 2, 7, 2, 8, 5, 4, 5, 1, 6, 5, 2, 4, 1
SK2, 0, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3, 1, 6, 9, 2, 9, 7, 8, 7, 3, 6, 3, 5, 5, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 6, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1
SK4, 2, 9, 5, 7, 0, 8, 6, 6, 7, 9, 0, 1, 3, 1, 6, 0, 0, 1, 3, 8, 5, 4, 0, 9, 7, 1, 4, 5, 2, 8
SK5, 2, 6, 8, 0, 3, 5, 5, 2, 5, 9, 4, 5, 3, 5, 7, 8, 8, 2, 5, 9, 3, 8, 6, 7, 8, 7, 4, 1, 2, 3
SK6, 2, 7, 5, 9, 1, 9, 8, 4, 1, 7, 3, 7, 0, 8, 4, 5, 9, 2, 4, 4, 8, 7, 9, 2, 2, 7, 9, 1, 6, 9
SK7, 6, 9, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 3, 8, 7, 1, 9, 6, 1, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 5, 9, 1, 4, 4, 0, 2, 0
SK8, 2, 8, 8, 3, 1, 1, 0, 8, 5, 9, 0, 3, 1, 6, 8, 7, 9, 6, 7, 7, 0, 9, 5, 2, 5, 0, 2, 1, 8, 6
SK9, 7, 1, 8, 8, 4, 4, 2, 2, 7, 4, 0, 6, 9, 5, 5, 4, 9, 1, 8, 6, 3, 4, 8, 2, 7, 9, 7, 2, 6, 6
```

Comment: Hint: you posted some requirements, and some code. But you are not giving a concrete input example, and you are also not telling us what exactly you are struggling with. Thus: please improve your question. And turn to the help center to learn how to ask better questions!

Comment: @GhostCat My apologies, updated the question to make it, hopefully, a bit clearer

Comment: You use `splitline.tail.head` which is just the second element of the list, you want to map over the tail instead: `splitline.tail.map(_.toInt)`. Also change the type of `mapBuffer` to `Map[String, List[Int]]`.

Comment: And ah, please only use tags that matter. I cant actually help with scala questions, as I am not so fluent there!

Comment: Do you want to get ("SK1" -> Seq(9,7,2,0,7...)),("SK2" -> Seq(0,7,6,...))  ? The method return type is `Map[String, Int]`, so I am not sure what you need. Do you want a `Map[String, Seq[Int]]`?

Comment: @laughedelic is there anychance you could send me my code edited to show what you mean? I am trying myself but im getting conforming errors

Comment: @AndreQueen I'll write an answer

Comment: @laughedelic That would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code with minimal changes:

```
// I split it on two functions just to facilitate testing:
def readFile(filename: String): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
  processInput(Source.fromFile(filename).getLines)
}

def processInput(lines: Iterator[String]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
  var mapBuffer: Map[String, List[Int]] = Map()
  try {
    for (line <- lines) {
      val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList

      // here instead of taking .tail.head, we map over the tail (all numbers):
      mapBuffer = mapBuffer + (splitline.head -> splitline.tail.map(_.toInt))
    }
  } catch {
    case ex: Exception => println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
  }
  mapBuffer
}
```

And here is a solution, which I believe, is more a idiomatic Scala code:

```
import scala.util.Try

def processInput(lines: Iterator[String]): Map[String, List[Int]] = {
  Try {
    lines.foldLeft( Map[String, List[Int]]() ) { (acc, line) =>

      val splitline = line.split(",").map(_.trim).toList
      acc.updated(splitline.head, splitline.tail.map(_.toInt))
    }
  }.getOrElse {
    println("Sorry, an exception happened.")
    Map()
  }
}
```

The differences mainly are

- not using `var`
- not using mutable `Map` (by the way, you don't need a `var` to mutate
  it)
- using [`foldLeft`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.Iterator@foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B) to iterate and accumulate the `Map` instead of `for`
- using
  [`scala.util.Try`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.util.Try)
  instead of try-catch.

Comment: This is a little unrelated @laughedelic but If i was wanting to find the highest of each of the lists now, how would I go about that? I know im suppose to create a new question but I thought this would save time and a small pointless post. Like SK1 - 9

Comment: @AndreQueen you should familiarize yourself with Scala documentation and search it better. To find maximum of a list of numbers you can use [`max`](http://scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List@max:A) method.

Comment: I have a decent understanding of the basics, but Im unsure how to use it in this case. For instance, If i had "val highest = mapdata.max" it would not work, I am not sure how to go through the lists and get the max for each @laughedelic

Comment: Don't take it as an offense, but I don't think that it's a decent understanding. Check some tutorials on Scala collections and how to map over them, fold them, etc. Here is [one](http://www.brunton-spall.co.uk/post/2011/12/02/map-map-and-flatmap-in-scala/), but I don't know if it's good. The answer to your particular question is `mapdata.mapValues { _.max }`

Comment: No offence taken, without criticism how can we learn? You are right, Ill look into more tutorials before I ask anymore questions, thanks for your help! @laughedelic

Comment: There is some relevant documentation written on StackOverflow: [Collections](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/686/collections#t=201611102210382158087), [Working with data in immutable style](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/scala/6298/working-with-data-in-immutable-style#t=201611102210282422295)